# Pretty simple content slider

Tags: jquery

I´m trying to implementig Pretty Simple Content Slider from 
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/04/28/pretty-simple-content-slider-with-jquery-and-css3/
but when i try to put the same code twice the second module don't work.

Any ideas?
Thanks

```
     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
     <html>
     <head>
    <title>Pretty Simple Content Slider with jQuery and CSS3</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="description" content="Pretty Simple Content Slider with jQuery and CSS3" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="jquery,css3, content slider, slide, auto-play"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>

    <style>
        *{
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }
        body{
            font-family:Arial;
            background:#C1C7D5 url(title.png) no-repeat top center;
        }
        a.back{
            background:transparent url(back.png) no-repeat top left;
            position:fixed;
            width:150px;
            height:27px;
            outline:none;
            bottom:0px;
            left:0px;
        }
        #content{
            margin:150px auto 10px auto;
        }
        .reference{
            clear:both;
            width:800px;
            margin:30px auto;
        }
        .reference p a{
            text-transform:uppercase;
            text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #fff;
            color:#666;
            text-decoration:none;
            font-size:10px;
        }
        .reference p a:hover{
            color:#333;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <a class="back" href=""></a>

        <div class="rotator">
            <ul id="rotmenu">
                <li>
                    <a href="rot1">Portfolio</a>
                    <div style="display:none;">
                        <div class="info_image">1.jpg</div>
                        <div class="info_heading">Our Works</div>
                        <div class="info_description">
             At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio
            dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium
            voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et
            quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate
            non provident... 
                            <a href="#" class="more">Read more</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="rot2">Services</a>
                    <div style="display:none;">
                        <div class="info_image">2.jpg</div>
                        <div class="info_heading">We serve</div>
                        <div class="info_description">
             At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio
            dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium
            voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et
            quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate
            non provident...
                            <a href="#" class="more">Read more</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="rot3">Contact</a>
                    <div style="display:none;">
                        <div class="info_image">3.jpg</div>
                        <div class="info_heading">Get in touch</div>
                        <div class="info_description">
             At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio
            dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium
            voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et
            quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate
            non provident...
                            <a href="#" class="more">Read more</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="rot4">Experiments</a>
                    <div style="display:none;">
                        <div class="info_image">4.jpg</div>
                        <div class="info_heading">We do crazy stuff</div>
                        <div class="info_description">
             At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio
            dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium
            voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et
            quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate
            non provident...
                            <a href="#" class="more">Read more</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="rot5">Applications</a>
                    <div style="display:none;">
                        <div class="info_image">5.jpg</div>
                        <div class="info_heading">Working things</div>
                        <div class="info_description">
                            At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio
            dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium 
            voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et 
            quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate 
            non provident... 
                            <a href="#" class="more">Read more</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div id="rot1">
                <img src="" width="800" height="300" class="bg" alt=""/>
                <div class="heading">
                    <h1></h1>
                </div>
                <div class="description">
                    <p></p>

                </div>    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="reference">
        <p><a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/jrparis/106493273/">1 http://www.flickr.com/photos/jrparis/106493273/</a></p>
        <p><a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/aussiegall/2104652119/">2 http://www.flickr.com/photos/aussiegall/2104652119/</a></p>
        <p><a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/intherough/4396089594/">3 http://www.flickr.com/photos/intherough/4396089594/</a></p>
        <p><a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/lightknight/628680053/">4 http://www.flickr.com/photos/lightknight/628680053/</a></p>
        <p><a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/nguyendai/404631197/">5 http://www.flickr.com/photos/nguyendai/404631197/</a></p>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <a class="back" href=""></a>

        <div class="rotator">
            <ul id="rotmenu">
                <li>
                    <a href="rot1">Portfolio</a>
                    <div style="display:none;">
                        <div class="info_image">1.jpg</div>
                        <div class="info_heading">Our Works</div>
                        <div class="info_description">
             At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio
            dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium
            voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et
            quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate
            non provident... 
                            <a href="#" class="more">Read more</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="rot2">Services</a>
                    <div style="display:none;">
                        <div class="info_image">2.jpg</div>
                        <div class="info_heading">We serve</div>
                        <div class="info_description">
             At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio
            dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium
            voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et
            quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate
            non provident...
                            <a href="#" class="more">Read more</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="rot3">Contact</a>
                    <div style="display:none;">
                        <div class="info_image">3.jpg</div>
                        <div class="info_heading">Get in touch</div>
                        <div class="info_description">
             At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio
            dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium
            voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et
            quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate
            non provident...
                            <a href="#" class="more">Read more</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="rot4">Experiments</a>
                    <div style="display:none;">
                        <div class="info_image">4.jpg</div>
                        <div class="info_heading">We do crazy stuff</div>
                        <div class="info_description">
             At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio
            dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium
            voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et
            quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate
            non provident...
                            <a href="#" class="more">Read more</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="rot5">Applications</a>
                    <div style="display:none;">
                        <div class="info_image">5.jpg</div>
                        <div class="info_heading">Working things</div>
                        <div class="info_description">
                            At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio
            dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium 
            voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et 
            quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate 
            non provident... 
                            <a href="#" class="more">Read more</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div id="rot1">
                <img src="" width="800" height="300" class="bg" alt="" style="left: 0px; top: 0px"/>
                <div class="heading">
                    <h1></h1>
                </div>
                <div class="description">
                    <p></p>

                </div>    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- The JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function() {
            var current = 1;

            var iterate     = function(){
                var i = parseInt(current+1);
                var lis = $('#rotmenu').children('li').size();
                if(i>lis) i = 1;
                display($('#rotmenu li:nth-child('+i+')'));
            }
            display($('#rotmenu li:first'));
            var slidetime = setInterval(iterate,3000);

            $('#rotmenu li').bind('click',function(e){
                clearTimeout(slidetime);
                display($(this));
                e.preventDefault();
            });

            function display(elem){
                var $this   = elem;
                var repeat  = false;
                if(current == parseInt($this.index() + 1))
                    repeat = true;

                if(!repeat)
                    $this.parent().find('li:nth-child('+current+') a').stop(true,true).animate({'marginRight':'-20px'},300,function(){
                        $(this).animate({'opacity':'0.7'},700);
                    });

                current = parseInt($this.index() + 2);

                var elem = $('a',$this);

                    elem.stop(true,true).animate({'marginRight':'0px','opacity':'1.0'},300);

                var info_elem = elem.next();
                $('#rot1 .heading').animate({'left':'-420px'}, 500,'easeOutCirc',function(){
                    $('h1',$(this)).html(info_elem.find('.info_heading').html());
                    $(this).animate({'left':'0px'},400,'easeInOutQuad');
                });

                $('#rot1 .description').animate({'bottom':'-270px'},500,'easeOutCirc',function(){
                    $('p',$(this)).html(info_elem.find('.info_description').html());
                    $(this).animate({'bottom':'0px'},400,'easeInOutQuad');
                })
                $('#rot1').prepend(
                $('<img/>',{
                    style   :   'opacity:0',
                    className : 'bg'
                }).load(
                function(){
                    $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},600);
                    $('#rot1 img:first').next().animate({'opacity':'0'},700,function(){
                        $(this).remove();
                    });
                }
            ).attr('src','images/'+info_elem.find('.info_image').html()).attr('width','800').attr('height','300')
            );
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Please post your code. Are you duplicating IDs?

Comment: i just ducplicate the main div. is the following html http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/PrettySimpleContentSlider/

Comment: How can i grop the id´s in the same jquery code?